# Google Compute Engine: error 403 from OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-compute-engine

I enabled the Google Compute Engine API billing and I added my email to my project through the console. Then I opened the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) page for testing.

Step 1. I selected the Compute Engine API v1, then I selected the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly
```

step 2. I clicked on 'Exchange authorization code for tokens'.

step 3: I sent a GET request to the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/smtvpn-20130716/zones/europe-west1-b/instances
```

I think I passed the API authorization, but it reports:

```
Access Not Configured.
Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your ......
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [APIs-explorer's `instances.list`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.instances.list).